# Laravel + Tailwind CSS - Classes not available due to being in Variables

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, tailwind-css

So I recently started a Laravel 10 + Vite + Tailwind CSS project (using [Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze)), simply to see how it all worked, due to me being out of the Laravel ecosystem for a while. By default, it works great; Vite is able to detect and compile just fine, something like:

```
<input type="text" class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900"/>
```

Results in the `<input>` being rendered, and in dark mode, it's background being set to `gray-900`.

However, I very much dislike how "loud" the classes can get. Because Tailwind uses a "building blocks" approach, where each element can have multiple classes applied, which then translate to individual style rules, something like a simple `<a>` tag can have a crazy amount of styles, like:

```
<a href="#" class="text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800">Example</a>
```

In Bootstrap, or other CSS frameworks, you'd simply do something like:

```
<a href="#" class="link">Example</a>
```

And the associated styles from `.link { ... }` would be applied.

---

With all that preamble aside, I tried to do something more dynamic. This approach works great, and allows me to do something like:

```
<a href="#" class="{{ $theme->__('link') }}>Example</a>
```

This uses a `.` (Dot) Notation method to apply the classes from my `link` Array key, so the finalized HTML is identical to the statically-typed version above:

```
$theme = [
  'link' => 'text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800',
// ... Others
];

public function __($path) {
  // ... Logic to construct `$output` from supplied `$path` and local `$theme` Array

  return $output;
}
```

The only problem, and it's a big one, is that none of the Classes apply any styles, due to how Tailwind CSS analyzes your `*.php` or `*.blade.php` files to determine *which* classes need to be included. When it looks at the `.blade.php` files, it only sees `{{ $theme->__('link') }}`. When it looks at the compiled `.php` classes in `storage/framework/views`, it only sees `<?php echo e($theme->__('link')); ?>`, so it ends up compiling *none* of the available classes, and the `<a>` is left unstyled...

---

So, my question is, **is there a way to use Tailwind CSS with variables**? I suspect if I needed to, I could simply output all of my `$theme` array values to a hidden Element, or a static `.html` file, so Tailwind would find that and compile the classes as needed, but that feels gross...

---

Edit: `tailwind.config.js` is the default that comes with Laravel + Breeze:

```
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import forms from '@tailwindcss/forms';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [forms]
};
```

Comment: The variables in tailwindcss are done in the tailwind.config.js. I'm not a tailwind expert so also look at other responses. The variables you use are the usual css variables. Did you construct your own tailwind.config.js or did you keep it pretty basic? (empty)

Comment: @UnderDog `tailwind.config.js` is the default that comes with Laravel + Breeze (edited question too). But again, it's scanning the `.blade.php` and `.php` files, which doesn't contain anything like `bg-red-100` (or similar), but rather `{{ $theme->__('link') }}` (`.blade.php`) or `<?php echo e($theme->__('link')); ?>` (`.php`). I need it to inspect the compiled HTML, but it's looking like I need to do that via custom logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that for the file that contains this code:

```php
$theme = [
  'link' => 'text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800',
  // …
];
```

is covered by the `content` file globs in your Tailwind configuration. By doing  that, Tailwind will see the class text strings and generate the associated CSS rules.

Comment: Oh interesting; so even if it just finds the text anywhere in that file, it'll load them? Let me give this a try, one sec.

Comment: Very nice! I just finished writing a method to convert my `$theme` array to a flat HTML file, but I guess that's redundant if it can simply look at the entire file. Thanks!